# Dynamically generated textfield not showing the value set by javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically generated textfield (using the following code):

```
echo "<div><table width='100%'><tr>
         <td>
             Date: <input type='text' class='span2' id='currDate'>
         </td><td rowspan='2'></td></tr></table>";
```

This field is generated once a user presses a button, this button links to a javascript:

```
$('#receipts button').live('click', function(){
        var id = this.id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "post", url: "receipt-stock.php", data: "production_detail_id="+id,
            success: function(data) {
                $('.modal-body').html(data);
                $('#new_receipt').modal('show');
                var myDate = new Date();
                var prettyDate = myDate.getDate()+'-' +(myDate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+myDate.getFullYear();
                $("#currDate").val(prettyDate);
                $('#currDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
            }
        });
    });
```

As it can be seen from the javascript i am displaying a modal which contains the textfield from the code above. Everything works fine except the part where i am setting the value of `#currDate` to the current date, the textfield does not show anything nether it shows the date-picker when in focus.

**However upon using alert i found that the textfield has the value i want, it just doesn't  display it.**

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but have you tried calling `datepicker()` before setting the value of the input?

Comment: @jprofitt - that doesn't work either!

Comment: Is this code either after the input, or wrapped in a `$.ready()`? If you're executing this before the input has been put into the DOM, your JavaScript is not going to see it.

Comment: Is this live somewhere where we can see it in action? Could be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is after you do `.modal()`, you have two elements with the id `#currDate`, which isn't valid HTML. Without seeing the entire page, it's hard to say for sure, but I've seen this problem quite a bit actually. jQuery will find the first ID, and that's the element that is getting your value set.

The exact fix is hard to say without seeing the rest of the code. You might try setting the value of the currDate element before you call `.modal()`. If there is a way to change currDate to a class or unique ID, that may help. Alternatively, you might be able to change the code you have to something like `$('#new_reciept #currDate').val(prettyDate);`.

Comment: I don't they are two separate elements, they are referring to the same one.

Answer (score 0):

As a previous poster says, it is the `.datepicker()` call that is blanking out the date. you can add a parameter `defaultDate: new Date()` that should allow you to remove the code above and give the results you desire.

Also, your input element is never closed
`<input type='text' class='span2' id='currDate' >` should be `<input type='text' class='span2' id='currDate' />`

Comment: It doesn't work even if i comment out the `.datepicker()` part

Comment: I see, your input is never closed!

Comment: @vari `/>` is not needed unless he's using XHTML, and even then it's not going to matter here as the browser has already read the element into the DOM. More info on HTML5 and self-closing tags: http://tiffanybbrown.com/2011/03/23/html5-does-not-allow-self-closing-tags/